# Can you access a web server that is located on the VPN server while connected to the VPN server?

Tags: openvpn

If I have an OpenVPN server and I am connected to it from my PC somewhere. How would I access a web server that is also on the VPN server?

Comment: Connecting to VPN server does not make any change. Are you missing some info which clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can establish a VPN link to that server, so you have a route to it. Now you can access web server by the IP using as server address in OpenVPN client.

Also you can access the web server with remote IP address when you have connected to the VPN server.

Answer (score 0):

With a single ip address on a vpn server, using nat, one cannot access the web server using that address, since the server and the client have the same IP address.

However, one can use the nat ip address of the server (example: server 10.8.0.1, client 10.8.0.2, therefore the two can route packets).

On an Amazon server with an Elastic IP address, the Elastic IP cannot be used, but the internal Amazon ip address can be used to access.